# Why after_commit not running even with use_transactional_fixtures = false

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, commit, rspec2, rspec-rails

Transactional fixtures in rspec prevent after_commit from being called, but even when I disable them with

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
end
```

The `after_commit callback` does not run.

Here is a rails app with the latest rspec / rails that I have produced the issue on:
[git://github.com/sheabarton/after_commit_demo.git](https://github.com/sheabarton/after_commit_demo)

Comment: After_commit callback was added to tests in Rails 5.0+ https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/18458

Answer (score 28, accepted):

One way around this is to trigger the `commit` callbacks manually.  Example:

```
describe SomeModel do
  subject { ... }

  context 'after_commit' do
    after { subject.run_callbacks(:commit) }

    it 'does something' do
      subject.should_receive(:some_message)
    end
  end
end
```

A little late, but hope this helps others.

Answer (score 9):

In my case I resolved such problem with database_cleaner's settings placed below:

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

config.before(:suite) do
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :deletion
  DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
end

config.before(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.start
end

config.after(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
end
```

Thanks to [Testing after_commit/after_transaction with Rspec](https://devblog.supportbee.com/2012/01/14/testing-after_commitafter_transaction-with-rspec/)

Comment: This is actually the proper answer in most cases, although the deletion and truncation strategies are much slower than transactions.

Answer (score 8):

This is similar to @jamesdevar's answer above, but I couldn't add a code block, so I have to make a separate entry.

You don't have the change the strategy for the whole spec suite. You can keep using `:transaction` globally then just use `:deletion` or `:truncation` (they both work) as needed. Just add a flag to the relevant spec.

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

config.before(:suite) do
  # The :transaction strategy prevents :after_commit hooks from running
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
end

config.before(:each, :with_after_commit => true) do
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
end
```

then, in your specs:

```
describe "some test requiring after_commit hooks", :with_after_commit => true do
```

Comment: This is a great solution that doesn't involve with object's `run_callbacks` and you don't have to install a new gem!

Answer (score 5):

If you're using [database_cleaner](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner) you'll still run into this. I'm using the [test_after_commit](https://github.com/grosser/test_after_commit) gem, and that seems to do the trick for me.

Comment: This gem is outdated after upgrade ruby to 2.4+

Answer (score 2):

[This Gist](https://gist.github.com/990357) helped me.

It monkey-patches ActiveRecord to fire after_commit callbacks even if using transactional fixtures.

```
module ActiveRecord
  module ConnectionAdapters
    module DatabaseStatements
      #
      # Run the normal transaction method; when it's done, check to see if there
      # is exactly one open transaction. If so, that's the transactional
      # fixtures transaction; from the model's standpoint, the completed
      # transaction is the real deal. Send commit callbacks to models.
      #
      # If the transaction block raises a Rollback, we need to know, so we don't
      # call the commit hooks. Other exceptions don't need to be explicitly
      # accounted for since they will raise uncaught through this method and
      # prevent the code after the hook from running.
      #
      def transaction_with_transactional_fixtures(options = {}, &block)
        rolled_back = false

        transaction_without_transactional_fixtures do
          begin
            yield
          rescue ActiveRecord::Rollback => e
            rolled_back = true
            raise e
          end
        end

        if !rolled_back && open_transactions == 1
          commit_transaction_records(false)
        end
      end
      alias_method_chain :transaction, :transactional_fixtures

      #
      # The @_current_transaction_records is an stack of arrays, each one
      # containing the records associated with the corresponding transaction
      # in the transaction stack. This is used by the
      # `rollback_transaction_records` method (to only send a rollback hook to
      # models attached to the transaction being rolled back) but is usually
      # ignored by the `commit_transaction_records` method. Here we
      # monkey-patch it to temporarily replace the array with only the records
      # for the top-of-stack transaction, so the real
      # `commit_transaction_records` method only sends callbacks to those.
      #
      def commit_transaction_records_with_transactional_fixtures(commit = true)
        unless commit
          real_current_transaction_records = @_current_transaction_records
          @_current_transaction_records = @_current_transaction_records.pop
        end

        begin
          commit_transaction_records_without_transactional_fixtures
        rescue # works better with that :)
        ensure
          unless commit
            @_current_transaction_records = real_current_transaction_records
         end
        end
      end
      alias_method_chain :commit_transaction_records, :transactional_fixtures
    end
  end
end
```

Put this a new file in your Rails.root/spec/support directory, e.g. `spec/support/after_commit_with_transactional_fixtures.rb`.

Rails 3 will automatically load it in the test environment.

Comment: This worked for me but made my specs unusably slow. Going to swap to using after_save instead for now though I'm concerned it may not 100% align with my business logic in all cases.