# What is "with_after_commit" and why can't I find anything about it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails, database-cleaner

I helping out on a test suite that came from Rails 4 (which I am not so familiar with) and there were some tests that had "with_after_commit: true" in their declaration.

After a bit of tinkering I removed it and the test suite ran a little bit faster.

It was used in rails_helper.rb as well, much like this:
[Why after_commit not running even with use_transactional_fixtures = false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656942/why-after-commit-not-running-even-with-use-transactional-fixtures-false/26849392#26849392)

The thing is: I can't find any information about it that would justify its use. I only find references to it in the thread above.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is the ActiveRecord callback called `after_commit`, not `with_after_commit` (this is just the name of your test case).

It's documented [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html#method-i-after_commit) and you can find plenty of resources if you just Google it.

It's also good to take a look at the [Active Record Callbacks Guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html).

Comment: I think what OP was asking about is something like this:
`context 'blah blah blah', with_after_commit: true do ... end`, which is exactly what I'm trying to find out.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I had the same question, so I'm sharing what I figured out for posterity.

What you're seeing is an [RSpec filter](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-11/docs/hooks/filters), which is basically a hook that can be selectively invoked.

So, [in the question you cited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656942/why-after-commit-not-running-even-with-use-transactional-fixtures-false/26849392#26849392), the example shows the following filter:

```ruby
config.before(:each, :with_after_commit => true) do
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
end
```

Then the spec is defined as:

```ruby
describe "", :with_after_commit => true do
  #...
end
```

So, the `with_after_commit => true` is what allows the `before(:each)` hook to fire.